# Fantasy author includes books about a bloodline involving flames and wolves

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the books years ago in the nineties and early 2000s. There were multiple books by the author, just don’t remember if they were in a series or just set in the same world. The books were about a monarchy and their right to rule was based on some mystical bloodline they had that involved wolves if I’m remembering right and flames for sure. It was a female author but I can’t remember her name at all or any of the book titles.

Comment: Possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_Wolf%27s_Eyes?

Answer (score 3):

Wow that took forever to figure out. The author is Fiona Patton the series of books is called The Branion Realm. Four books included in it. [image]

Comment: You will be able to self accept by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour] in about 39 hours.